# How to get difference sum of between keys in a Dictionary object C#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, dictionary

I have one dictionary with key as some integer value which is an index of array and a string in value field.I need the sum of difference between the keys in the same dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, string> foo = new Dictionary<int, string>() 
{
  {0,"text1"},
  {2,"text2"},
  {6,"text3"},
  {8,"text4"}
};
```

**Output**

- (8-6)=2
- (6-2)=4
- (2-0)=2

> Total: 2+4+2=8

Comment: shouldn't that simply be always max key - min key?

Comment: Subtraction is not commutative, order matters a great deal.  Dictionary is not an ordered collection.

Comment: @HansPassant My Dictionary object will be always ordered like what is above.so no worry

Comment: It is not, Dictionary is *not* an ordered collection.  If you see an order then you just got lucky.  That luck will run out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be the difference between the Max Key and Min Key.

```
int total = foo.Keys.Max() - foo.Keys.Min();
```

Answer (score 3):

Thus all other key values will be both added and subtracted during totals calculations, you need only max and min here:

```
var total = foo.Max(kvp => kvp.Key) - foo.Min(kvp => kvp.Key);
```